# Convert TimeSpan from format "hh:mm:ss" to "hh:mm"

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, timespan

I want to show in a TextBox only hour and minutes

```
var test = dataRow.Field<TimeSpan>("fstart").ToString();  
//test ="08:00:00"  
var tb = (TextBox) gridViewRow.Cells[2].FindControl("fstart");
tb.Text = test;
```

how to show only hours and minutes `"hh.mm"`

Comment: A tip would be to have a look at [Roslyn CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34685) which I've found very useful for testing formatting in C# if you are using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You need to convert your data to TimeSpan and then use format:`"hh\:mm"`

```
string test ="08:00:00";
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(test);
Console.Write(ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm"));
```

In your case:

```
var test = dataRow.Field<TimeSpan>("fstart").ToString(@"hh\:mm"));
```

Remember to escape the colon `:`

You may see: [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)

Comment: If Same occurs in ASP .net there are no such methods like .Tostring() with argument acceptance.

Comment: @Rahul, overloaded `TimeSpan.ToString` methods were provided in .Net framework 4.0. I guess the ASP.Net application you are referring to is using a previous version of .Net framework.

Answer (score 16):

There is no need to convert from `hh.mm.ss` to `hh.mm`. `TimeSpan` is stored as a number of ticks (1 tick == 100 nanoseconds) and has no inherent format. What you have to do, is to convert the `TimeSpan` into a human readable string! This involves formatting. If you do not specify a format explicitly, a default format will be used. In this case `hh.mm.ss`.

```
string formatted = timespan.ToString(@"hh\.mm");
```

Note: This overload of `ToString` exists since .NET 4.0. *It does not support date and time placeholder separator symbols! Therefore you must include them as (escaped) string literals.*

The usual way of formatting strings seems not to work for some odd reason (tested with .NET 3.5). (It does not make any difference whether you escape the separator symbol or not):

```
var timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1234);
string formatted = String.Format(@"{0:hh\.mm}", timespan); // ==> 00:20:34
```

However, you can construct the string like this

```
string formatted =
    String.Format("{0:00}.{1:00}", Math.Floor(timespan.TotalHours), timespan.Minutes);
```

or starting with VS2015 / C# 6.0, using string interpolation:

```
string formatted = $@"{timespan:hh\:mm}";
```

Comment: Don't forget Math.Floor() on the TotalHours.
Without this 29,7h => Gets converted to 30:42...

Answer (score 8):

You can use TimeSpan methods:

```
ToString("hh':'mm")
// or
ToString(@"hh\:mm")
```

Also check all available formats here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: TimeSpan.ToString doesn't support this formatting. see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx)

Comment: This is new in .Net 4

Answer (score 3):

```
var test = dataRow.Field<TimeSpan>("fstart").ToString("hh.mm");  
//test ="08:00"  
var tb = (TextBox) gridViewRow.Cells[2].FindControl("fstart");
tb.Text = test;
```

Comment: If the input contains the `:` , it will fail on fomrat `hh.mm`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question. If anyone wants to show single-digit hours when your hours are a single digit then you can use

```
var hoursWithMinutes = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours).ToString(@"h\:mm")
```

This way, when your hours are double-digit I mean greater than 9 then it will be showing 10:00 something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The previous solutions don't run if hours>24, try this solution if you have time in minutes very big

```
int minutes = 159000;
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(0, minutes, 0);

String HOURS = Math.Round(t.TotalHours, 0).ToString();
if (HOURS.Length==1)
{
    HOURS = "0"+HOURS;
}


String MINUTES = t.Minutes.ToString();
if (MINUTES.Length == 1)
{
    MINUTES = "0" + MINUTES;
}


String RESULT = HOURS + ":" + MINUTES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by:

```
  var hhmm = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).ToString(@"hh\:mm")
```