# How to convert hours from h to hh in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I was able to convert the minutes to hours and minutes. e.g. 35 minutes is converted to 0:35 and 65 minutes to 1:5.

But I would like it to be displayed in the format of 00:35 and 01:05 respectively for previous two examples. Any suggestions here?

I tried the below code

```
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(intMins);           
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", ts.Hours,  ts.Minutes ) );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use string format `00`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", ts.Hours,  ts.Minutes));
```

Or see the following SO post for formatting `TimeSpan` objects:

[Convert TimeSpan from format "hh:mm:ss" to "hh:mm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673194/convert-timespan-from-format-hhmmss-to-hhmm)