# Get time span value in hh:mm format to a string variable

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

```
DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime('2015/06/20');
DateTime date2= Convert.ToDateTime('2015/05/20');
TimeSpan latetime = date1.Subtract(date2);//here in 'hh:mm:ss' format
string value=latetime.ToString();
```

I get value as in `hh:mm:ss` format.But I want to get it only `hh:mm` format

Comment: [`string value=latetime.ToString("hh:mm");`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert TimeSpan from format "hh:mm:ss" to "hh:mm"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673194/convert-timespan-from-format-hhmmss-to-hhmm)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code won't *even* compile. You need to use double quotes for strings, not single quotes.

```
DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime("2015/06/20");
DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime("2015/05/20");
```

By the way, what you see (*as a forma*t) on `TimeSpan latetime = date1.Subtract(date2);` line is probably just a debugger representation. A `TimeSpan` doesn't have any implicit format itself. *Formatting* concept only will be an issue when you try get it's *textual* representation.

And `TimeSpan` formatting is little bit different than `DateTime` formatting. You can use `hh\\:mm` format like;

```
string value = latetime.ToString("hh\\:mm");
```

or you can use verbatim string literal;

```
string value = latetime.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

- [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
string value=latetime.ToString("hh\\:mm");
```

but result will be `00:00`
if you need days then :

```
string value=latetime.ToString("dd\\:hh\\:mm");
```

[MSDN - Custom TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you request could likely be a total hour:minute formatted string:

```
string value=((int)latetime.TotalHours).ToString() + ":" + latetime.ToString("mm");
```

This will return: `744:00`

Comment: I don't think OP wants a result as `744:00`.

Comment: WHO knows? The title of the question is pretty clear.